# Tap gesture recognizer getting in the way of selecting collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, which I can search through using a `UISearchBar`. I set it up so that when the user taps anywhere on the screen, the keyboard is dismissed.

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then:

```
@objc override func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```

It works at dismissing the keyboard but this tap gesture recognizer is getting in the way of selecting UICollectionView cells. The `didSelectItemAt` method just won't work.

Looking at another answer here, I managed to fix it somewhat by removing the gesture recognizer and just adding `dismissKeyboard()` in the `didSelectItemAt`. However, now it only dismisses if you tap the cell, and then the item selects (which I don't want, I just want the keyboard to dismiss).

How do I make it so that tapping anywhere on the screen when the keyboard is showing dismisses it, after which the `UICollectionView` cells work and can be selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to extend UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your viewcontroller and add this snips of code. then tap gesture will not work for collectionview and act normally for rest of view.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    if touch.view != self.yourCollectionView{
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try `tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
    
@objc func hideKeyboard() {
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectItemAt You can check, is Your UISearchBar is first responder.

```
if searchBar.isFirstResponder {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
} else {
    //do what You want
}
```

If You have another things, apart from cells, add Your gesture recognizer to dismiss keyboard

Comment: How do I add the gesture recognizer to everything but the uicollectionview cells?

Comment: If You don't "tap" on it, You can create clear uiview and add it to this

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it by adding a transparent view on top of everything and applying the gesture recognizer to it. On `viewDidLoad()` I set the view to `isHidden = true`.

Then added these:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        gestureView.isHidden = false

        return true
    }

    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        gestureView.isHidden = true

        return true
    }
```